# Скролл jQuery не работает в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, firefox

http://ewalliance.ru/

Ссылка на архив сайта: http://rgho.st/7QHT24Q8T

Скролл работает из меню работает во всех браузерах кроме Mozilla Firefox, с чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();


    var id = $(this).attr('href'),


    top = $(id).offset().top;


    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deactivatemenu").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();


    var id = $(this).attr('href'),


    top = $(id).offset().top;


    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();


    var id = $(this).attr('href'),


    top = $(id).offset().top;


    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});


window.onload = function() { 

    var scrollUp = document.getElementById('scrollup'); 

    scrollUp.onmouseover = function() { 
        scrollUp.style.opacity=0.8;
        scrollUp.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=30)';
    };

    scrollUp.onmouseout = function() { 
        scrollUp.style.opacity = 1;
        scrollUp.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=50)';
    };

    scrollUp.onclick = function() { 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1500);
    };



    window.onscroll = function () {
        if ( window.pageYOffset >= 200 ) {
            $(scrollup).stop().animate({opacity:'1.0'},100);
            scrollup.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            $(scrollup).stop().animate({opacity:'0.0'},100);
            scrollup.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
};




$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();


    var id = $(this).attr('href'),


    top = $(id).offset().top;


    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: У вас и в Chrome не очень хорошо работает: у меня получается скроллить по горизонтали.

Comment: @Дмитрий Можно установить причину?

Comment: Чтобы нельзя было скроллить по горизонтали стоит написать что-нибудь вроде `html, body { width: 100%; }`. Скролл в Firefox я пока не знаю как исправить.

Comment: Кстати эл-та с id #komy не существует

Comment: @Alex78191 Задал уже.

Comment: Может залить JS скрипт сюда?

Comment: @Дмитрий а как у Вас выходит скроллить по горизонтали?

Comment: С помощью скроллбара на ноутбуке. Двигаю двумя пальцами вниз, скроллится вниз (это хорошо), двигаю вправо и тоже скроллится (это плохо).

Comment: @Дмитрий Это довольно странно...

Я залил сайт архивом, посмотрите?

Comment: Ты через CSS что-то сломал.

Comment: @Alex78191 ну, я залил архив. Если поможете с этим вопросом, буду очень признателен, я совсем недавно это всё начал изучать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливай `overflow-x: hidden` или для `html` или `body`, но не для обоих.

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Иначе вместо использования `overflow-x` можно вручную убрать выступы элементов за ширину body.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Появился скролл по горизонтали

Comment: @user234223 обновил ответ

Comment: Уберу отступы, тогда объекты будут не по центру

Как быть с этим?

vertical-align поможет?

Comment: @user234223 какие элементы?

Comment: @Alex78191, а где можно такую красивую картинку сделать?

Comment: @Дмитрий Использовал дополнение [Tilt 3D](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/tilt/)

Comment: @Alex78191, ничего страшного, большое спасибо за наводку на дополнение.

Comment: @user234223 вы удовлетворены ответом?

Comment: @Alex78191 Да, остался ещё такой момент, как исправить всё это дело в Firefox, почему не скроллит там?

Comment: @user234223 я в ответе и написал как исправить.